# Puzzling SE in 2017

Tags: riddle, rhyme, seasonal

```
Now twenty sixteen has faded away:  
A terrible year, I really must say.  
People dying, relationships up messed,  
Elections and politics dividing the West.
```

---

*I turn over on my side,*
*For all is upside down.*
*I piss again and again,*
*But really, why bother?*

*Just west of north,*
*I exist, but backwards.*
*Now you are here,*
*Coming twice for me.*

*Why do we do it?*
*Existential crisis!*
*For all is wrong again,*
*And we must fill the gap.*

---

```
The above is a riddle to future from past.  
Here's to a better this year than last.  
Riddles and challenges must be solved  
On this great site, so far evolved.  
And to all of you, my wish for this year:  
That you find fun and ne'er shed a tear.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> Happy New Year!

It is hidden in the poem:

> I turn over on my side, — **H** looks like an `I` with long serifs rotated by 90°
>  For all is upside down. — **A** looks like ∀ (*for all*) upside down
>  I piss again and again, — **PP** sounds like "pee"
>  But really, why bother? — **Y** encoded as "why"
>
>  Just west of north, — **N** for the leftmost or western letter of North
>  I exist, but backwards. — **E** looks like ∃ (*exists*) on its head
>  Now you are here,
>  Coming twice for me. — **W** is a double "you"
>
>  Why do we do it? — **Y** is "why" again
>  Existential crisis! — **E** is "exists" upside down like above
>  For all is wrong again, — **A** is "for all" upside down like above
>  And we must fill the gap. — **R** in "we are" fills the gap

Comment: Well done, you successfully navigated the shoal of red herrings and found yourself here in 2017.

Comment: I'm not getting where that final R comes from.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: I'm not so sure, either, but I think it's either "are" filling the gap in "we —" or the R filling the gap in YEA—, although that's more like completing rather than filling.

Comment: @Chris It's a sort of meta-non-clue: once you've found HAPPY NEW YEA, you just need to "fill the gap" to get the R.

Comment: @rand Happy New Year :D

Answer (score 6):

Partial Findings -

> First letters of first part gives **NAPE**(Which is back of a person's neck)
>
>  **N**ow twenty sixteen has faded away:
>  **A** terrible year, I really must say.
>  **P**eople dying, relationships up messed,
>  **E**lections and politics dividing the West.
>
>  I think the middle part gives **on**
>
>  I tur**n o**ver **on** my side, -> on is turned to no
>  F**o**r all is **u**pside d**o**w**n**. -> ou is upside down of on
>  I piss again and again,
>  B**u**t really, why b**o**ther?
>  Just west of **no**rth, -> West of north but backwards
>  I exist, but backwards.
>  **No**w y**ou** are here, -> Twice Here
>  Coming twice for me.
>
>
>  First letter of the following part gives - **A FEW**
>  **W**hy do we do it?
>  **E**xistential crisis!
>  **F**or all is wrong again,
>  **A**nd we must fill the gap.
>
>
>  Taking first letter of the last part gives **THROAT**
>
>  **T**he above is a riddle to future from past.
>  **H**ere's to a better this year than last.
>  **R**iddles and challenges must be solved
>  **O**n this great site, so far evolved.
>  **A**nd to all of you, my wish for this year:
>  **T**hat you find fun and ne'er shed a tear.

So..

> I get **NAPE ON A FEW THROAT** which may or may not be the final answer :)

Comment: You've successfully caught a red herring by its **nape** and then finished it off with a quick slash to the **throat**.